# Find document with array values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Lets say I have these documents:

```
shirt1 = {colors: ["red"]}
shirt2 = {colors: ["blue"]}
shirt3 = {colors: ["red","blue"]}
```

If I do:

```
Shirt.find({ colors: "red" }, ...);
```

I would get shirt1 and shirt3 back right?

What would my query be if I only want:

- Only Shirt1
- Only Shirt1 and Shirt2
- Only Shirt3
- All shirts

I think this would give me all shirts right?

```
{'colors': {$in: ["red","blue"]}}
```

Comment: I guess you could still use the same syntax but saving the value of the find in a variable, then, you applying **length on it** and, if it is >1, it is an array, else it has a single value.

Comment: Why don't you try that and see what will happen?